# How can I block a game on my child's phone during the night?

Tags: parental-control, google-family-link, digital-wellbeing

My son is playing chess on the Chess.com app on his Android phone. I do not have issues with the total time he is using the app, but rather the time of day (e.g. just before school or late in the evening).

How can I restrict the usage of the app for him for only certain times of day? Note that there are other apps (e.g. maps) that I do not want to restrict at all, so blocking the whole phone down is not an option.

Comment: Please tell me the Phone Brand and model, and I'll try to help.

Comment: I have Pixel 7, my child Pixel 2